Logic of a set of permutations in $S_{10}$
Consider the following permutations $a,b,c\;{\in}\;S_{10}$;
$$a=(1\;2\;3\;4\;5),\;b=(6\;7\;8\;9\;10),\;c=(2\;7)(1\;6)$$
The question i am stuck on is whether a permutation, lets call it $\alpha$, composed of $a$, $b$, and $c$ can be created such that $\alpha=(1\;2)$.
If such permutation cannot be created, give a short reason for why not.
I believe this to be impossible only using $a$, $b$, and $c$. my reasoning is that 1 and 2 don't exist together in a cycle without 3, 4 and 5. There are no cycles that contain 3, 4, or 5 without containing 1 and 2, so there is no way to "correct" the changes to the other numbers after 1 and 2 are swapped without changing other numbers.
Is my logic correct, and if so how would i explain it more clearly?
Thanks in advanced

Have you heard of the parity of a permutation?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation

I have just realized that the permutation $a^4ca^3bca^4$ swaps 1 and 2, so i am now fairly stumped with how parity can be used

@MichaelLugo am i right in saying that $a,b,c$ all have even parity, whereas the transposition $(1,2)$ is odd, so no sequence of $a,b,$ or $c$ can create $(1,2)$?

that's exactly what I was thinking.  As for your claim that $a^4 c a^3 b c a^4$ swaps 1 and 2, often permutation computations can be a bit tricky - you might want to check that again.

@MichaelLugo ah yes, i wrote one of the 5-cycles incorrectly when computing it, and got the wrong result. Thanks for pointing this out
